# Facebook - posting to the new "what you're doing"-thing

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

So Facebook introduced a new feature allowing you to include not only links/pictures/locations to a post, but also a moods, music, videogames etc.

Does the Graph API allow you to post these somehow? As far as I can see, the ***post*** end point only supports "link"|"photo"|"video" -> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature to express actions in the status composer is still being rolled out to the public.

The Graph API does not allow you to post these at the moment.

It is built off Open Graph actions (e.g. feeling) and objects (e.g. happy), so I imagine this will come out in the later months.